# Draw 16 dots in Circular path with CGContextRef

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cgcontextref

How can I add 16 dot in circular path when the user select a location x,y in my View
and the dots should be in a equal distances,

so when the user hit a location in the view, I will complete the circle with 16 dot,
see attachment.

[image]

the image is the use from this code:

```
CGPoint CenterPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2);
CGPoint Point;
float Angel = 360/16;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 16;i++)
{
    float distance = [self distanceFrom:newPoint to:centerPoint];
    Point.x = CenterPoint.x + distance * cos(Angel);
    Point.y = CenterPoint.y + distance * sin(Angel);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(cacheContext, Point.x, Point.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(cacheContext, Point.x, Point.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(cacheContext);

    Angel+= 10;
}
```

Comment: I suspect trigonometry is involved...

Comment: Yes, trig is involved. Take a looky here http://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html you know the radius (once you have selected a centre point and you know the angle. You just need to move round the circle converting from polar to cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Just FYI: *angel* is the celestial do-gooder (usually with wings and a halo), and *angle* is the space between two intersecting lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code it may help you little

```
int startAngle = 0;

while (startAngle < 360)
{
    CAShapeLayer *slice = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    slice.fillColor = _buttonColor.CGColor;
    slice.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    slice.lineWidth = 3.0;

    CGFloat angle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-60.0);
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2.0, self.frame.size.height/2.0);
    CGFloat radius = self.frame.size.width/2.0;

    UIBezierPath *piePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [piePath moveToPoint:center];

    //[piePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + radius * cosf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(startAngle)), center.y + radius * sinf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(startAngle)))];

    [piePath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(startAngle) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(startAngle + 63) clockwise:YES];

    //   [piePath addLineToPoint:center];
    [piePath closePath]; // this will automatically add a straight line to the center
    slice.path = piePath.CGPath;

    startAngle += (360/15);

    [self.layer addSublayer:slice];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but this draws a full circle not only dots.

Comment: Do you have to draw only dots or you have to connect those dots also?

Comment: No, just dots without connecting those dots, but I've managed to do it finally, I'll post the answer today, thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The `cos` and `sin` functions expect the angle in radians and not degrees (which you are providing). Try this alternative approach instead.

```
float distance = [self distanceFrom:newPoint to:centerPoint];
CGContextSaveGState(cacheContext);
CGContextTranslateCTM(cacheContext, CenterPoint.x, CenterPoint.y);

for (int i = 0 ; i < 16;i++)
{
    float angle = i * (M_2_PI / 16);
    CGPoint pt = CGPointMake(distance * cos(angle), distance * sin(angle));

    CGContextMoveToPoint(cacheContext, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(cacheContext, pt.x, pt.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(cacheContext);
}
CGContextRestoreGState(cacheContext);
```

This approach translates the context so that the origin (a.k.a centre-point) really is the `CenterPoint` so you don't need to worry about adding `CenterPoint` to anything. Since `distance` is not affected by anything inside the loop, it should be moved out so that it is not recalculated unnecessarily.